# To clear up some doubts about moment.js

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I got stuck in my project, due to some doubts related to moment.js. I'll state some conclusions here I made during writing backend on project, and please can someone correct me if something is wrong?

For example, if I get datetime string from fronted, in format:
"THU 18 MAR 2017 09:20 AM", I should create moment object passing this string to it and corresponding token "ddd DD MMM YYYY HH:mm A" as passed string is not in standard ISO 8601 format.

```
var datetime = moment(datetimeFromFrontend, "ddd DD MMM YYYY HH:mm A");
```

Now I have moment object that can be formated in way I want, calling format() function on moment object. 
If I want to do some manipulations with datetime generally (for example, compare to today's datetime, or compare only time part), is it mandatory to convert all manipulating datetimes, times or whatever to moment object with same format and using isBefore, isEqual and so on, or can I somehow compare them using >, <, <=, =< ?

If I need to compare (>, < etc) datetime or just time part with value retrieved from SQL database (which is DATETIME or TIME data type), should I pass both comparing values to moment object, convert them in same format and then do manipulations?

And how to save to SQL database column which is DATETIME, or TIME type? Should do some transforms from moment object to string using format()? SQL will automatically convert passing string to corresponding data type?

Example:

```
var now = moment();
```

I assume that "now" can't be passed to sql query directly as it is moment object, it should be converted to string (and rely on SQL automatic conversion from string/nvarchar to datetime) or should I save it as `moment().toDate()`  ?

Comment: I believe you are looking for the [query functions](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I need to compare (>, < etc) datetime or just time part with value retrieved from SQL database (which is DATETIME or TIME data type), should I pass both comparing values to moment object, convert them in same format and then do manipulations?

You might want to lookup the docs for that
You have [Query functions](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/) that can compare moments and even Date objects, for example, this is the entry for the `.after` function

> moment().isAfter(Moment|String|Number|Date|Array);

as you can see, you can pass anything to `.isAfter` and it will do that job for you

```
moment().isAfter(new Date(2017, 2, 4))
// true
moment(new Date(2016, 2, 4)).isAfter(new Date(2017, 2, 4))
// false
```

Of course the easiest way to compare >, < or === is to get the timestamp using `Date::getTime`, but that's ugly code

> And how to save to SQL database column which is DATETIME, or TIME type? Should do some transforms from moment object to string using format()? SQL will automatically convert passing string to corresponding data type?

I think it depends how you SQL works and how your server communicates to it, ORACLE, you should refer to any documentation about storing date objects inside your sql, eventually dates and formats are all about making unix-timestamps human readable/understandable.

> I assume that "now" can't be passed to sql query directly as it is moment object, it should be converted to string (and rely on SQL automatic conversion from string/nvarchar to datetime) or should I save it as moment().toDate() ?

Ask yourself what kind of benefits you or anyone that may use you API will gain from getting agnostic Date objects from your DB rather then just plain strictly formatted strings?